# Postgresql, does pg_ctl promote affect primary server?

Tags: postgresql, replication

What will happen if I promote replica while primary server is still running? Does it affect the primary server in any way?
I know replica will lost it's continuity with primary but I'd like to set up new replica anyway.

I need to perform some actions on this replica database and I want to be sure nothing wrong will happen to primary.

Answer (score 0):

The effect on the primary is that the standby disconnects. That has two consequences:

1. there will be a little less load on the primary
2. if replication used a replication slot, that slot now stays at its position, WAL segments on the primary won't get deleted any more, and unless you set `max_slot_wal_keep_size`, your primary will run out of disk space and crash

So drop the replication slot used by the standby, if there is one, and you'll be fine.